# how to get intellisense (in vscode) for class properties declared inside constructor

Tags: javascript, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

Im using vscode, and trying to create js code that is intellisense friendly.

i cant create class properties because it dosnt go well with iphones in safari (because of ES7,8,9 whatever), so, im creating the class properties inside the constructor:

```
class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.property1 = "value1";
        this.property2 = "value2";
        this.property3 = "value3";
    }
}
```

but this way, i lose the cool intellisense telling me which stuff is properties from "Test" class.

is there any way to tell intellisense which are the properties of Test class?

Comment: should work out of the box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Mez.png

Answer (score 0):

ok, as georg point out, it should work, im nt sure the problem, i had lots of garbage extensions installed, i remove most and got working again :)